# Jsp Servlet Tomcat 6 Error - Unable to Load Servlets

Tags: jsp, servlets, tomcat6

This problem is intermittant and occurs every few times I try to connect to my web app from a client machine.

The jsp pages loads fine, any code within it executes fine, but as soon as I submit a form to a servlet, it cannot find the servlet.

Yet when on the server itself I can run the full application from netbeans with no problem, also I can run the full application on the server under IE7, no problems.

Any external connection can see the web pages but falls over on accessing a servlet.

As far as I am concerned everything seems to be in place, servlet libs are in both jdk/jre libs, the classpath is correct.

As a further test I created a new virtual server, installing netbeans, tomcat6 and copying over the original files and the same issue occurs.

Comment: After searching online I found that you need to place all your servlets in a package, otherwise the invoker servlet xml ref in tomcat cannot pick them up. now working, a total pain!!!!

Comment: and that's preferred for all java classes. Using no package is almost forbidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> servlet libs are in both jdk/jre libs

This is a very, *very* bad idea. The servlet libs are in essence already provided by the servletcontainer itself. In case of for example Tomcat, it's present in its `/lib` folder. When you manually put servlet libs of a different servletcontainer make/version in JDK/JRE libs, then I won't be surprised if the webapp start to behave like that.

At any way, *get rid* of servlet libs in JDK/JRE libs. Even more, you should never touch those libs. If you did it because you got compilation errors on missing `javax.servlet` imports when compiling servlets, then you should have solved it differently: specify the `Tomcat/lib/*` in the compiletime classpath.

---

Where did you learn about developing servlets? Did you read Roseindia tutorials or something? I'd suggest to put aside the book/tutorial you have used and continue with decent books/tutorials. You can find useful links at bottom of our [Servlets info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Comment: did the last big google algorithm change affect roseinidia? I think I haven't seen it too much recently, which is rather good.